# Best practice for vpn peering from office to multiple accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, vpn

I am chasing some general guidance for setting up my network and VPN peering.

Basically, I want to setup a connection from my office to aws, but am wondering what the best practice is for multiple aws accounts?

1. Should I setup the vpn peer from the office to just one account subnet, and then peer to the other account from that subnet or,
2. should I setup individual vpn peers to both/all accounts from the office

I am just chasing what is the normal best practice for network design in this case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can enable VPC Peering between accounts and their respective VPCs, but VPC Peering is not transitive, meaning that they will not forward packets. This means that if you use a VPN to connect to VPC-A and VPC-A is peering with VPC-B, your VPN traffic will NOT be forwarded to VPC-B thru VPC-A. So this eliminates VPC Peering as an option.

The best solution is to create a site-to-site VPN from your office to each account/VPC that you need connectivity with. I recommend that you look into a software solution such as OpenSwan or Windows Server Routing and Remote Access if you need company wide routing. AWS also lists a number of hardware routers that work very well. If just individuals need access then a good choice is OpenVPN (Desktop to AWS).

Keep in mind that there will be costs to enable site-to-site routing. You will either need AWS VGW or an EC2 instance running VPN software. This means a per hour cost 24 hours per day. VGW is $.05 per hour (for most regions). EC2 instance is around another $.05 per hour for a small instance. VGW is the better choice but then you are limited on what types of hardware / software that supports connections to VGW and its setup complexity. However, VGW allows you to use one VPN connection to route to multiple VPCs.

For more complex configurations / very high bandwidth, AWS and Cisco have partnered on the Cisco CSR. This is a high end solution with a high end cost. There is also Direct Connect for the best solution of all.

Your final choice will be determined by cost, software versus hardware solution, site-to-site or client-to-site, permanent always on routing or connect when required routing.

Comment: ok so it sounds like the better option is to have site to site peers to each accounts, (shared services) vpc and then peer to the internal vpc's from that (shared services) one. 

`* office -> aws (dev account : "shared services vpc") -> dev account vpc's/subnets`
`* office -> aws (prod account: "shared services vpc") -> prod account vpc's/subnets`

??

Comment: From what you were saying, it sounds like it would not even work to, create a site to site peer to one aws account vpc, and then peer from that vpc to other accounts   from there.

Comment: You would setup office -> VPC_A and office->VPC_B , etc. This is the simplest. However, if you know what you are doing, you could setup a shared VPC with say OpenSwan or Windows Server and then create VPC peers from that VPC to the others. Remember that you will need to setup static routes on all of the computers that will network with the AWS systems (basically one route per VPC).

Comment: Your network and each of the VPCs cannot have overlapping addresses (CIDRs).

Answer (score 0):

It's now possible to link multiple VPCs and your VPN connection with a Transit Gateway.
so you can use your vpn to connect to the TGW then connect to any VPC-A or VPC-B.
https://aws.amazon.com/transit-gateway/